# Agrupar datos de dos tablas distintas en MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

Tengo 4 tablas: `estudiantes`, `profesores`, `cursos` y `calificaciones`.

En este caso, lo que tengo que hacer es lo siguiente:

> "Crear un informe resumido de los cursos y sus notas medias, ordenados desde el curso más difícil (curso con la nota media más baja) hasta el curso más fácil"

Tengo entendido que lo que tengo que realizar es unir las tablas `Cursos` y `Calificaciones` con un subquery, pero estoy perdida. Esto es lo que he escrito:

```
SELECT c.course_name AS 'Course', AVG(grade) AS 'Average Grade'
FROM grades
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT course_name
    FROM courses
) AS c
ON c.course_name = grades_course_id
GROUP BY course_name
ORDER BY AVG(grade) ASC;
```

Tengo varias foreign keys relacionadas, y yo creo que como `grades_course_id`, que es la que intento unir con `course_name`, está vacía, pues no se puede. O también porque `grades_course_id` es `INT` y `course_name` es `VARCHAR`.

La cuestión es que lo hice con la tabla `Profesores` en vez de con la tabla `Cursos` (más que nada porque para cada curso hay un único profesor) y en este caso sí que funciona, pero porque es mucho más simple. Lo he intentado coger como ejemplo para construirlo con `Cursos` y `Calificaciones`, pero no sé dónde está el error.

```
SELECT grades_professor_id AS 'Professor', AVG(grade)
FROM grades
GROUP BY grades_professor_id
ORDER BY AVG(grade) ASC;
```

Por si os sirve de algo, os dejo unas capturas de las dos tablas y también del diagrama, para que veais un poco cómo lo he relacionado:

[image: Tabla 'Cursos']

[image: Tabla 'Calificaciones']

[image: Diagrama EER]

Comment: Hay alguna razon por la cual tengas las tablas `courses`, `professors` y `students` relacionadas con la tabla `grades` (las tres relacionadas en una tabla)?

Comment: Pues he relacionado `grades` y `professors` porque me pedían "calificación media dada por cada profesor". Y he relacionado `grades` y `students` porque me pedían "calificaciones top de cada estudiante", y con `courses` la he relacionado porque consideraba que estan relacionadas, no?

Comment: Para poder realizar el ejercicio tienes que tener claro la relacion y cardinalidad  de cada entidad en tu diagrama, recuerda que hay relaciones  `1*m` ,`m*m`, `1*1`.
De la forma que lo veo yo pienso que deberia ser de la siguiente forma: `Cursos` (1) tiene  (m) `Estudiantes`, estudiantes debe tener una `llave foranea` para saber en que curso esta el estudiante y asi con las demas tablas, para entender mejor esto te sugiero leer [Doc cardinalidad](https://www.ibm.com/docs/es/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=r-cardinality)

Comment: tambien para entender mejor podrias leer [programacion orientada a objetos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos) y tambien [diagrama de clases](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagrama_de_clases)

Comment: Gracias David, me lo leo!!! :)

Comment: @David081 Una pregunta, si tengo relación `1*1` (tipo Curso-Profesor), ¿debería tener Profesor una `llave foránea`?

Comment: si, en una relacion 1-1 profesor deberia tener una foranea, *Sin embargo* considero que la relacion curso- profesor deberia ser 1-*, porque si tienes varios Cursos/Asignaturas en tu instituto/Colegio no creo que tengas un solo profesor. [aca hay informacion acerca de 1-1](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/es/index.html#page/FMP_Help/one-to-one-relationships.html)

Comment: Entiendo lo que me comentas, lo que pasa es que había supuesto que era `1*1` porque he pensado que *un* curso/asignatura tiene *un único* profesor, y *un* profesor *solo imparte una* asignatura (al menos en este ejercicio), ¿tiene sentido?

Comment: si, tiene sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error lo tienes al intentar combinar un nombre con un número, concretamente el `c.course_name` con el `grades_course_id`. Deberías hacer:

```
SELECT c.course_name AS 'Course',
  AVG(grade) AS 'Average Grade'
  FROM grades
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT id_course,course_name
        FROM courses
  ) AS c
  ON c.id_course= grades_course_id
  GROUP BY course_name
  ORDER BY AVG(grade);
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias David! Finalmente hice esto y salió, no tenía claro si estaba bien, pero viendo tu respuesta ya veo que sí, así que gracias!!